# Expo Android App does not require any permissions by default

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo, android-permissions, expo-permissions

The documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/#android-permissions) states that an android app will require all permissions by default. However, mine does not require any. I have not provided **android.permissions** in my **app.json**

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

In Android 6 and higher the permission are no longer checked on install
[runtime requests](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#runtime_requests_android_60_and_higher)

Comment: Thanks for the link. One more thing I noticed is that in Android 10, it requires the physical  activity permission by default. Would you know why that's the case?